# Can't run Roboelectric test

Tags: android, robolectric, android-testing

I keep on getting

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   android/content/pm/PackageManager$NameNotFoundException ...
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: couldn't load
>   android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException... Caused by:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Any idea what causes this and how to get it fixed?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

your `jar file` may be `corrupted`so re add the jar file or`rebuild` the path of jar file ... clean the project and re run it.

Comment: This problem occurs only when my emulatedSdk is set to 21. Using the SDK Manager, I deleted that SDK and reinstalled it, but it is still not working.

Comment: OK then try to upgrade your SDK version from 21 to above, but in most of the cases this problem is occurred due to corrupted .jar file

Answer (score 0):

You need install sources for android-21 from Android SDK

Comment: this should be in comment