# robolectric test fails in cli with java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/content/pm/PackageManager$NameNotFoundException

Tags: android, robolectric

My test using robolectric is failing when I run "gradle test" from the command line, but it passed in Android studio.

But eventually I need to configure my project in CI so need to tun build and test from cli.

So, how could I go about this?

This here is the exception stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/content/pm/PackageManager$NameNotFoundException
    at hkhc.electricspock.internal.ElectricSpockInterceptor.interceptSpecExecution(ElectricSpockInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.AbstractMethodInterceptor.intercept(AbstractMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:87)
    at hkhc.electricspock.ElectricSputnik.run(ElectricSputnik.java:214)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:117)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:155)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:137)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/content/pm/PackageManager$NameNotFoundException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3090)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3295)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2110)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getHooksInterface(RobolectricTestRunner.java:507)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.beforeTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:323)
    at hkhc.electricspock.internal.ContainedRobolectricTestRunner.containedBeforeTest(ContainedRobolectricTestRunner.java:124)
    at hkhc.electricspock.internal.ElectricSpockInterceptor.interceptSpecExecution(ElectricSpockInterceptor.java:56)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: couldn't load android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.maybeInstrumentClass(SandboxClassLoader.java:132)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.lambda$findClass$0(SandboxClassLoader.java:107)
    at org.robolectric.util.PerfStatsCollector.measure(PerfStatsCollector.java:50)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.findClass(SandboxClassLoader.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to instrument android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.ClassInstrumentor.instrument(ClassInstrumentor.java:125)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.InvokeDynamicClassInstrumentor.instrument(InvokeDynamicClassInstrumentor.java:18)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.ClassInstrumentor.instrumentToBytes(ClassInstrumentor.java:67)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.lambda$maybeInstrumentClass$2(SandboxClassLoader.java:124)
    at org.robolectric.util.PerfStatsCollector.measure(PerfStatsCollector.java:50)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.maybeInstrumentClass(SandboxClassLoader.java:123)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.ClassNodeProvider.createClassNode(ClassNodeProvider.java:24)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.ClassNodeProvider.getClassNode(ClassNodeProvider.java:16)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.ClassInstrumentor.isOverridingFinalMethod(ClassInstrumentor.java:218)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.ClassInstrumentor.createInstrumentableMethodIfNotAlreadyPresent(ClassInstrumentor.java:236)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.ClassInstrumentor.instrument(ClassInstrumentor.java:105)
```

Answer (score 0):

The key issue is here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: couldn't load android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException
```

This simply tells us: there is a difference in your *setup* between android studio, and the information that you put into your gradle build setup!

In Java, you need to correctly specify your **dependencies** so that A) the compiler can find them for compiling and then B), at runtime, the JVM can *load* the classes you are using.

You can start reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-classnotfoundexception) for the underlying issue, beyond that, for your specific issue [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33303739/cant-run-roboelectric-test) might be helpful.

In the end, it must be about subtle differences in the setup of your android studio versus gradle configurations, in the area of dependencies.